# Can I process fermented pickles in a water bath?

Tags: food-safety, food-preservation, fermentation, pickles, lactofermentation

I'm new to fermenting.

Can I safely process fermented dill pickles in a water bath to ensure a longer storage life?

I have made pickles in the past, using vinegar, and then processing for 20 minutes in a water bath. Is this safe and effective with fermented pickles?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  The National Center for Home Food Preservation recommends [low temperature pasteurization](https://nchfp.uga.edu/how/can_06/dill_pickles.html) for fermented pickles, where you put them in a 180F water bath for 30 minutes.  This avoids softening the pickles through cooking.  Make sure that they have completed fermenting before this, as the pasteurization will stop the fermentation process.

Comment: Thanks.I assume that means processing will destroy any probiotic bacteria and therefore the health benefits from fermenting?

Comment: I can't possibly speculate on health benefits, but yes, it will destroy any bacteria.  That's the point of pasteurization. You can have the "good" bacteria, or you can have shelf-stable pickles, but you can't have both at the same time.

Comment: Ah ... did this not answer the question you asked?